# How to change the port of the rocketmq

Tags: rocketmq

i known the rocketmq's nameserver port is 9876 (default), here i can changed the port to 9877 (example)  like this

echo "listenPort=9877" > port.properties

nohup sh mqnamesrv -c port.properties &

then  netstat -tunlp |grep 9877

```
# » netstat -tunlp |grep 9877
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9877                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17808/java
```

now i want to  bind ip like this   192.168.1.10:9877, do not bind like 0.0.0.0

dose anyone knows ?

Answer (score 0):

RocketMQ not support modify nameServer port

[image]

but，you can forward ports through linux with iptables，searching on your own